# Wordpress/WooCommerce function working only with specific product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I figured out how to show WooCommerce shortcode below featured image for specific product but I can't figure out how to change showing code for a specific product category, not single product:

```
function custom_product_shortcode() {

    global $product;
    $id = $product->id;
    if($id==2895){
      echo "".do_shortcode('[we_calendar defaultdate="" cat="training-basic"]'); 
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'custom_product_shortcode', 9);
```

Anyone could help me with this one?

Comment: Huh? Is this a serious question? `if($id==2895){` So you are doing the shortcode output only if `$product->id == 2895`

Comment: Does the Product object contain a Category